# traefik v2 forwarding to external host. Non container host

Tags: traefik

I am looking for examples of traefik v2 forwarding to other host such as virtual machines ( ie non container ).

Kind Regards,
Edward

Comment: add more details to get the correct answers

Answer (score 0):

That should look like this in the file-provider:

```
http:
      routers:
        ...
        ...
      services:
        somename:
          loadBalancer:
            servers:
              - url: http://yourserverip
```

Docker has to "see" your server (test with curl or ping). 
Further information: [Traefik Docs - Routers](https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/)